# Match any word in string except those preceded by a curly brace in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like

```
line = u'I need to match the whole line except for {thisword for example'
```

I have a difficulty doing this. What I've tried and it doesn't work:

```
# in general case there will be Unicode characters in the pattern
matchobj = re.search(ur'[^\{].+', line) 

matchobj = re.search(ur'(?!\{).+', line)
```

Could you please help me figure out what's wrong and how to do it right?

P.S. I don't think I need to substitute `"{thisword"` with empty string

Comment: what is your objective? Do you want each word using re?

Comment: I'm not sure if I got you right, but I want a single line finally, which excludes words starting with { brace, because in lines I have to parse, there are comments in {here is a comment} format

Comment: ok you have many misunderstanding I post answer with some an examples.

Comment: @Grijesh Thank you, I'm waiting for it

Comment: your welcome, I posted an answer, I hope it help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly clear what you need. From your question title It looks you wants to find "All words in a string e.g 'line' those doesn't starts with {", but you are using re.search() function that confuses me.

#### `re.search()` and `re.findall()`

The function [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.RegexObject.search) return *a* corresponding MatchObject instance, re.serach is usually used to match and return a patter in a long string. *It doesn't return all possible matches*. See below a simple example:

```
>>> re.search('a', 'aaa').group(0) # only first match
'a'
>>> re.search('a', 'aaa').group(1) # there is no second matched
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: no such group
```

With regex `'a'` search returns *only one* patters `'a'` in string `'aaa'`, it doesn't returns all possible matches.

If your objective to find – "all words in a string those doesn't starts with `{`". You should use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) function:- that matches all occurrences of a pattern, not just the first one as re.search() does. See example:

```
>>> re.findall('a', 'aaa')
['a', 'a', 'a']
```

**Edit:** On the basis of comment adding one more example to demonstrate use of re.search and re.findall:

```
>>> re.search('a+', 'not itnot baaal laaaaaaall ').group()
'aaa'                 # returns ^^^   ^^^^^ doesn't 
>>> re.findall('a+', 'not itnot baaal laaaaaaall ')
['aaa', 'aaaaaaa']    #          ^^^   ^^^^^^^ match both
```

Here is a good tutorial for Python re module: [re – Regular Expressions](http://pymotw.com/2/re/index.html#module-re)

Additionally, there is concept of group in Python-regex – "a matching pattern within parenthesis". If more than one groups are present in your regex patter then re.findall()  return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group. see below:

```
>>> re.findall('(a(b))', 'abab') # 2 groups according to 2 pair of ( )
[('ab', 'b'), ('ab', 'b')] # list of tuples of groups captured
```

In Python regex `(a(b))` contains two groups; as two pairs of parenthesis (this is unlike regular expression in formal languages – regex are not exactly same as regular 
expression in formal languages but that is different matter).

---

**Answer**: The words in sentence `line` are separated by spaces (other either at starts of string) regex should be:

```
ur"(^|\s)(\w+)
```

Regex description:

1. `(^|\s+)` means: either word at start or start after some spaces.
2. `\w*`:  Matches an alphanumeric character, including "_".

On applying regex `r` to your line:

```
>>> import pprint    # for pretty-print, you can ignore thesis two lines
>>> pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

>>> r = ur"(^|\s)(\w+)"
>>> L = re.findall(r, line)
>>> pp.pprint(L)
[   (u'', u'I'),
    (u' ', u'need'),
    (u' ', u'to'),
    (u' ', u'match'),
    (u' ', u'the'),
    (u' ', u'whole'),
    (u' ', u'line'),
    (u' ', u'except'),
    (u' ', u'for'),   # notice 'for' after 'for'
    (u' ', u'for'),   # '{thisword' is not included
    (u' ', u'example')]
>>>
```

To find all words in a single line use:

```
>>> [t[1] for t in re.findall(r, line)]
```

Note: it will avoid { or any other special char from line because \w only pass alphanumeric and '_' chars.

---

If you specifically only avoid `{` if it appears at start of a word (in middle it is allowed) then use regex: `r = ur"(^|\s+)(?P<word>[^{]\S*)"`.

To understand diffidence  between this regex and other is check this example:

```
>>> r = ur"(^|\s+)(?P<word>[^{]\S*)"
>>> [t[1] for t in re.findall(r, "I am {not yes{ what")]
['I', 'am', 'yes{', 'what']
```

---

**Without Regex:**

You could achieve same thing simply without any regex as follows:

```
>>> [w for w in line.split() if w[0] != '{']
```

---

**re.sub() to replace pattern**

If you wants to just replace one (or more) words starts with `{` you should use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace patterns start with `{` by emplty string `""` check following code:

```
>>> r = ur"{\w+"
>>> re.findall(r, line)
[u'{thisword']
>>> re.sub(r, "", line)
u'I need to match the whole line except for  for example'
```

---

**Edit** Adding Comment's reply:

The `(?P<name>...)` is Python's Regex extension: (it has meaning in Python) -  `(?P<name>...)` is similar to regular parentheses - create a group (a named group).  The group is accessible via the symbolic group name. Group names must be valid Python identifiers, and each group name must be defined only once within a regular expression. example-1:

```
>>> r = "(?P<capture_all_A>A+)"
>>> mo = re.search(r, "aaaAAAAAAbbbaaaaa")
>>> mo.group('capture_all_A')
'AAAAAA'
```

example-2: suppose you wants to filter name from a name-line that may contain title also e.g mr use regex: `name_re = "(?P<title>(mr|ms)\.?)? ?(?P<name>[a-z ]*)"`

we can read name in input string using `group('name')`:

```
>>> re.search(name_re, "mr grijesh chauhan").group('name')
'grijesh chauhan'
>>> re.search(name_re, "grijesh chauhan").group('name')
'grijesh chauhan'
>>> re.search(name_re, "ms. xyz").group('name')
'xyz'
```

Comment: Great answer indeed! That's when I love SO, getting answers like that! Though I still have to reread it several times to understand, and now I'm stuck with P<word> . What is that? Is it some mistyping?

Comment: @rightaway717 No it has some meaning, it is python extention in Regex, wait I add about that (I also  think there is some miskate in answer I am adding about that wait)

Comment: @rightaway717 thanks for marking my answer usable, I removed some text, as I think it would unnecessary for some new user.

Comment: thank you so much for such an extended answer and great effort. It solved the problem and helped me make a more complicated task!

Comment: I still have a question. You wrote: "re.search is usually used to match and return a pattern in a long string. It doesn't return all possible matches". but with first example you gave I can do: re.search('a+', 'aaa').group() and get that long string. Well I actually need a long string in the end. Are there any reasons to use findall in my case and then concatenate list, or using search pattern to get the whole string is my way to go?

Comment: @rightaway717 What I mean to say is re.search() function search a pattern in a line and return that pattern to you e.g `>>> re.search('a+', 'not itnot baaal lll ').group()` -- will return you `'aaa'` back. But I used `re.findall()` because I had impression you need to find all words just not a single.

Comment: @rightaway717 See this exmaple: `>>> re.search('a+', 'not itnot baaal laaaaaaall ').group()` in the second argument there is two substrings of `'a'`  but re.seach returns first one only that is `'aaa'` (first one b/w 'b' and 'l')

Comment: @rightaway717 Whereas use findall with same re on same string `>>> re.findall('a+', 'not itnot baaal laaaaaaall ')` returns `['aaa', 'aaaaaaa']`

Comment: *"Are there any reasons to use findall in my case and then concatenate list, or using search pattern to get the whole string is my way to go"* See if you wants to replace a patter then you should use `re.sub()` as I given in answer. findall and search just search  word(s)

Comment: @rightaway717 Here is a good tutorial: [Python's re module](http://pymotw.com/2/re/index.html#module-re)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do:

`(?<!{)(\b\w+\b)` with the `g` flag enabled (all matches)

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/zA0sL6

Comment: could you please tell me where exactly to put "g" in search method? If it's a flag, than my python doesn't accept it, and I can't find it in docs. It's not clear from the link you provided where to put "g". Another question is what "<" sign means in your answer? Can't find it in docs too.

Comment: @rightaway717, You should use `findall` instead of `match`. This will give you a list of all matching strings. Also, the `<` means to match anything in the second set of parenthesis only if it is not preceeded by a {. That is what the `?<!` is used for.

Comment: Ok, now it seems working. Last question, why { is not escaped with backslash and not cosidered a control character? Thank you for your answers

Comment: @rightaway, when inside `[]` or `(?)`, you don't need to escape control characters. Rules of regex. If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thank you and Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
(.*)(?:\{\w+)\s(.*)
```

**Code:**

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(.*)(?:\{\w+)\s(.*)')
str = "I need to match the whole line except for {thisword for example"

p.match(str)
```

**Example:**

http://regex101.com/r/wR8eP6